# To dispaly number of weeks from starting date to ending date

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

I want to give the starting date and ending date as input and i need the List of week numbers between that dates.
For example:
If i give Starting date as 01/11/2019 and Ending date as 14/12/2019 and my output will be as

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
```

(because first 5 is for weeks of november month and next 3 is for weeks of december month).....and let us see another example: If i give Starting date as 14/11/2019 and Ending date as 14/12/2019 and my output will be as

```
3
4
5
1
2
3
```

(because first 3 is for weeks of november month and next 3 is for weeks of december month) ....

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2019-11-01'
SET @EndDate = '2019-12-14'
SET @CurrentDate = @StartDate
WHILE (@CurrentDate < @EndDate)
BEGIN
Print datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, @CurrentDate)/7 * 7)/7 + 1
SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7, @CurrentDate); 
END
```

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using.

Comment: What you have done post that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add the relevant tags only, the tag list is not your CV.

Comment: how do you define a "week number" within a month? i.e. clearly the 1st of the month will be in week one always ... but when does week 2 start? - i.e. what would you expect for date range `10 nov 2019` to `3 Dec 2019` and `11 Nov 2018` to `8 Dec 2019`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below script-

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2019-11-01'
SET @EndDate = '2019-12-14'
SET @CurrentDate = @StartDate


WHILE (@CurrentDate < @EndDate)
BEGIN

IF datepart(DD,@CurrentDate) <=7 
BEGIN 
    SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(DD,-(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate)-1),@CurrentDate) 
END 


PRINT datepart(dd,@CurrentDate)/7  +1
SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7, @CurrentDate); 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This One For batter result with week start date and end date

```
DECLARE @StartDate   datetime, 
        @EndDate     datetime, 
        @CurrentDate datetime, 
        @IsTrue      BIT=0 

SET @StartDate = '2019-11-01' 
SET @EndDate = '2019-12-14' 
SET @CurrentDate=@StartDate 

WHILE ( @CurrentDate <= @EndDate ) 
  BEGIN 
      IF( Format(@CurrentDate, 'MM') != Format(@StartDate, 'MM') 
          AND @IsTrue = 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @CurrentDate=Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, @CurrentDate), 0) 

            PRINT @CurrentDate 

            SET @IsTrue=1 
        END 

      SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ( Datepart(week, @CurrentDate) - 
                                    Datepart(week, 
                                    Dateadd(day, 1, Eomonth( 
                                    @CurrentDate, -1))) ) + 1), 
             @CurrentDate, 
             Dateadd(day, 6, @CurrentDate) 

      PRINT( CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ( Datepart(week, @CurrentDate) - 
                                    Datepart(week, 
                                    Dateadd(day, 1, Eomonth( 
                                    @CurrentDate, -1))) ) + 1) ) 

      SET @CurrentDate = Dateadd(day, 7, @CurrentDate); 
  END
```